# Hawking and Ellis's example of an extendible manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, semi-riemannian-geometry

In S. Hawking's and  G. Ellis's book "The Large-Scale Structure of Space Time", they discuss the notion of inextendible Lorentz manifolds $(M,g)$ (see chapter 3.1). A Lorentz manifold is called *inextendible* if there is no isometric embedding into a larger Lorentz manifold.

As an example of an extendible manifold, they name the two-dimensional real plane $(M_1,g_1)$ with the $x$-axis removed between $x_1=-1$ and $x_1=+1$. The obvious extension is the "complete" real plane, where the removed points are simply replaced,

> but one could also extend it by taking another copy $(M_2 , g_2)$ of the space, and identifying the bottom side
> of the $x_1$-axis for $|x_1| < 1$ with the top side of the $x_2$-axis for $|x_2| < 1$,
> and also identifying the top side of the $x_1$-axis for $|x_1| < 1$ with the
> bottom side of the $x_2$ -axis for $|x_2| < 1$. The resultant space $(M_3, g_3)$ is
> inextendible, but not complete as we have left out the points $x_1 = ± 1, y_1 = 0$. We cannot put these points back in because we were perverse enough to extend the top and bottom sides of the $x$-axis on different sheets.

I do not fully understand this construction.

- Is $(M_2,g_2)$ a copy of $(M_1, g_1)$ or a copy of the "complete" Euclidean plane?
- Are $x_1$ and $x_2$ the $x$-coordinates of $M_1$ and $M_2$, respectively?
- What do they mean by "the bottom side" and "the top side"? Does this mean that $-1<x_1\leq 0$ is identified with $0\leq x_2<1$ via $t\mapsto -t$?
- What happens to the points of $(M_1,g_1)$ and $(M_2,g_2)$ away from the $x$-axes. Are they identified as well?

Comment: $M_2$ is a copy of $M_1$, not of the euclidean plane. $x_1, x_2$ are the $x$ coordinates of $M_1, M_2$. Think of "top" and "bottom" sides as portals, you have removed a segment and a path that is going towards the segment either comes from the top or bottom. If it comes from the top it takes a portal to $M_2$ and exits into the bottom of $M_2$. The points away from the $x$-axis are not glued. This glued space is also the Riemann surface of $\sqrt{1-z^2}$, you can find pictures of this but they are not as helpful as I would have expected.

Comment: Hello @s.harp, so if I get you right, we have the following: $M_1=\{(x_1,y_1)\in\mathbb{R}^2\}-\{|x_1|\leq 1\}$ and $M_2=\{(x_2,y_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2\}-\{|x_2|\leq 1\}$. We set $M_3=M_1\sqcup M_2/\sim$, where the relation $\sim$ is defined via $(x,0)\sim(-x,0)$ for $(x,0)\in M_1$ and $(-x,0)\in M_2$. How can we now prove that this is indeed inextendible? Couldn't there be some "wild" Lorentzian manifold containing $M_3$?